# Necesito Guardar el resultado de este query en el resultSet [rsf] como lo hago por favor!

Tags: java

```
    String sql = "SELECT trainings.TRAINING_NAME AS capacitacion_nombre, area_members.area as area ," +
            "beneficted_area.TRAINING_MONTH as month , AVG(beneficted_area.TRAINING_SCORE) AS score" +
            "FROM " +
            "area_members,beneficted_area ,trainings " +
            "WHERE area_members.name=beneficted_area.PARTICIPANT_NAME " +
            "AND trainings.ID_TRAINIG=beneficted_area.ID_TRAINIG" +
            "group by area,month, capacitacion_nombre ORDER BY `CAPACITACION_NOMBRE` ASC";

    jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, rowNum) -> this.rsf = rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera con una lista del objeto que quieras guardar recorres `rs` con un `while` y puedes `settear` los valore en ese objeto para poder agregarlo a la lista.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
List<AreaMembers> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (rs.next()) {
  AreaMembers info = new AreaMembers();
  info.setAdId(rs.getInt("ad_id"));
  ...
  list.add(info);
}
```